# How to check two optional UITextFields

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 `UITextFields`: One is VehiclePlateNumber and other one is TrailerPlateNumber. Both of them are optional. 
But if both of them are missing then I will show a message when I click NEXT button.
The problem is that I can’t manage to go on the next screen with only 1 `UITextField` filled up. At the moment I need to fill up both of them to go on next screen and I don’t want this. 
Here is my code:

```
class RegistrationNumber {

    var vehicleRegistrationNumber: String?
    var trailerRegistrationNumber: String?

    init(vehicleRegistrationNumber: String?, trailerRegistrationNumber: String?) {
        self.vehicleRegistrationNumber = vehicleRegistrationNumber
        self.trailerRegistrationNumber = trailerRegistrationNumber
    }
}

// I was thinking to use this enum somehow. Or maybe is possible with guardlets ?
enum isValid {
        case vehicle
        case trailer
        case vehicleAndTrailer
    }

// When user press Next button
    @IBAction func nextBtnTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        let selectInspection = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SelectInspectionVC") as! SelectInspectionVC

        selectInspection.receivedRegistrationNumber = RegistrationNumber(vehicleRegistrationNumber: vehicleRegTextField.text, trailerRegistrationNumber: trailerRegTextField.text)

        let spinner = UIViewController.displaySpinner(onView: self.view)

        if notContainsVehicleReg(){
            showAlertWithTitle(message: "Wrong vehicle registration.")
            UIViewController.removeSpinner(spinner: spinner)
            print("Vehicle don't exist in list !!!")
        }
        else if notContainsTrailerReg(){
            showAlertWithTitle(message: "Wrong trailer registration.")
            UIViewController.removeSpinner(spinner: spinner)
            print("Trailer don't exist in list !!!")
        }
        else if vehicleRegTextField.text.isBlank && trailerRegTextField.text.isBlank{
            showAlertWithTitle(message: "Vehicle registration or/and Trailer Code required.")
            UIViewController.removeSpinner(spinner: spinner)
        }
        else{
            UIViewController.removeSpinner(spinner: spinner)
            navigationController?.pushViewController(selectInspection, animated: true)
        }
    }

fileprivate func notContainsVehicleReg() -> Bool {

        let filteredVehicles: [String] = vehiclesArray.map { $0.code.uppercased() }

        return !filteredVehicles.contains(vehicleRegTextField.text ?? String())
    }

    fileprivate func notContainsTrailerReg() -> Bool {

        let filteredTrailers: [String] = trailersArray.map { $0.code.uppercased() }

        return !filteredTrailers.contains(trailerRegTextField.text ?? String())
    }

// Extension to check if an optional String is empty or contain blank spaces
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
    var isBlank: Bool {
        if let unwrapped = self {
            return unwrapped.isBlank
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
}

// Check if a textfield don't contain white spaces or is empty
extension String {
    var isBlank: Bool {
        return self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty
    }
}
```

Thanks if you try to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the validation for this 2 `UITextFields` like this:

```
// Check if VehicleTextField contains any plate number from array of vehicles
    fileprivate func notContainsVehicleReg() -> Bool {

        let filteredVehicles: [String] = vehiclesArray.map { $0.code.uppercased() }

        return !filteredVehicles.contains(vehicleTextField.text ?? String())
    }

// Check if TrailerTextField contains any plate number from array of trailers
    fileprivate func notContainsTrailerReg() -> Bool {

        let filteredTrailers: [String] = trailersArray.map { $0.code.uppercased() }

        return !filteredTrailers.contains(trailerTextField.text ?? String())
    }

    // Check if VehicleTextField is blank
    fileprivate func vehicleIsBlank() -> Bool {
        return vehicleTextField.text.isBlank
    }

    // Check if TrailerTextField is blank
    fileprivate func trailerIsBlank() -> Bool {
        return trailerTextField.text.isBlank
    }

    // When user press Next button
    @IBAction func nextBtnTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        let selectInspection = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SelectInspectionVC") as! SelectInspectionVC

        selectInspection.receivedRegistrationNumber = RegistrationNumber(vehicleRegistrationNumber: vehicleTextField.text, trailerRegistrationNumber: trailerTextField.text)

        let spinner = UIViewController.displaySpinner(onView: self.view)

        if vehicleIsBlank() && trailerIsBlank() {
            showAlertWithTitle(message: "Vehicle registration or/and Trailer Code required.")
        }
        else if (!vehicleIsBlank() && notContainsVehicleReg()) && (trailerIsBlank()){
            showAlertWithTitle(title: "Vehicle not found", message: "Add vehicles via the PreDrive website to they are available for inspection.")
        }
        else if (!vehicleIsBlank() && notContainsVehicleReg()) && (!trailerIsBlank()){
            showAlertWithTitle(title: "Vehicle not found", message: "Add vehicles via the PreDrive website to they are available for inspection.")
        }
        else if (!trailerIsBlank() && notContainsTrailerReg()) && (vehicleIsBlank()){
            showAlertWithTitle(title: "Trailer not found", message: "Add trailers via the PreDrive website to they are available for inspection.")
        }
        else if (!trailerIsBlank() && notContainsTrailerReg()) && (!vehicleIsBlank()){
            showAlertWithTitle(title: "Trailer not found", message: "Add trailers via the PreDrive website to they are available for inspection.")
        }
        else if (!vehicleIsBlank() && notContainsVehicleReg()) && (!trailerIsBlank() && notContainsTrailerReg()){
            showAlertWithTitle(title: "Vehicle and Trailer not found", message: "Add vehicles and trailers via the PreDrive website to they are available for inspection.")
        }

        UIViewController.removeSpinner(spinner: spinner)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(selectInspection, animated: true)
    }

    // Check if VehicleTextField or TrailerTextField contains spaces at beginning, then remove them
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        let vehicleTextField = textField
        let trailerTextField = textField

        let vehicleString = "\(vehicleTextField.text ?? String())\(string )"
        let trailerString = "\(trailerTextField.text ?? String())\(string )"

        if (vehicleString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).count == 0) || (trailerString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).count == 0) {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

Obviously is a better way but I've done it using a pen and a paper and thinking all the possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

just change your nextBtnTapped(:UIBarButton) function to this.
this will check if both textFields are empty or not and if one or both of them are right filled it will go to next ViewController.

```
        @IBAction func nextBtnTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

            let spinner = UIViewController.displaySpinner(onView: self.view)

            if vehicleRegTextField.text.isBlank && trailerRegTextField.text.isBlank{
                showAlertWithTitle(message: "Vehicle registration or/and Trailer Code required.")
                UIViewController.removeSpinner(spinner: spinner)
            } else {
                let selectInspection = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SelectInspectionVC") as! SelectInspectionVC

                selectInspection.receivedRegistrationNumber = RegistrationNumber(vehicleRegistrationNumber: vehicleRegTextField.text, trailerRegistrationNumber: trailerRegTextField.text)
                UIViewController.removeSpinner(spinner: spinner)
                navigationController?.pushViewController(selectInspection, animated: true)
            }
        }
```

Comment: And do you know how can I make the validation for each UITextField ? Because with this solution I can type any PlateNumber and will take me to next screen. But the problem is that I need to validate each field to see if the plateNumber is in my array or not.